# MySQL trying to reuse results of subquery in an efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT q,COUNT(x),y,
    (SELECT i FROM (SELECT q,w FROM tableA WHERE conds)
     JOIN tableC ON (cond)
     WHERE id = t.q)
FROM (SELECT q,w FROM tableA WHERE conds) t
JOIN tableB
GROUP BY q
```

The subquery `(SELECT q,w FROM tableA WHERE conds)` returns several hundred rows. After the `GROUP BY q` there is around 20 rows left.

The subquery `(SELECT i FROM (SELECT q,w FROM tableA WHERE conds) join tableC WHERE id = t.q)` uses inside of it the exactly same subquery as the one above, but then also selects a fraction of the results based on which `q` value is currently being grouped.

My problem seems to be this. The performance is too slow because I can't seem to put the `WHERE id = t.q` inside the `(SELECT q,w, FROM Table A WHERE conds)` subquery. I can only guess that for every unique value of `q`, the query is being run, it produces hundreds of rows and then has to perform the `WHERE` clause on an un-indexed temporary table. I think I need to perform the WHERE before the full join

Any ideas please?

Comment: a test case on http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be very helpful

Comment: Your query is not valid, subqueries in the `SELECT` list should return one column only, and you are doing `(SELECT i, j ...)`

Comment: Quite right. Made an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query could produce the same results, but so much information is missing from the question, who can be sure?

```
Select 
    q,
    count(x),
    y,
    i
From 
    tableA a
       inner join
    tableC c
       on cond and c.id = a.q
       cross join -- is this an inner join?
    tableB b
Where
    conds
Group By
    q, 
    y, 
    i
```